# std::vector causes heap crash

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a strange heisenbug which appears in x86 Release mode under VC11 C++.  Unfortunately I wasn't able to come up with a minimal example which still has the bug, however here is one that works fine:

```
#include "stdafx.h" // <- nothing special in here
#include <vector>

class MyClass {
    std::vector<double> myVec;
public:
    void init(int m) {
        myVec = std::vector<double>(m); // (3)
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    MyClass x; // (1)
    x.init(1); // (2)
}
```

Now in (1) I create a an instance of MyClass where myVec should be default constructed as empty vector.  In (2) I call init which changes the value of myVec, see (3).  There I get somethimes an error.

The error is always an heap error during deallocation of the original content of myVec.  It seems like myVec does not contain any memory but it tries to free it anyway.  However, the error occours only in Release mode, not always (like in 80% of the cases, despite the fact that the algorithm runs always on the same data and has no random elements), and it occours never while stepping through the program with the debugger (it is actually enough to have a break point in this line and always press F5 to continue).

I could fix the problem by using

```
    myVec.resize(0);
    myVec.resize(m);
```

instead of (3).  But what I now fear is that I still have a bug somewhere in my program that caused undefined behaviour and for that reason myVec was not properly constructed (or at least somehow came in inproper state).  I have just no clue how such a bug could look like and where to start looking for it.

Has anyone have had some similar problem before and an idea how to systematically find the cause of error?  I know it's hard to make a remote diagnostics in this case but any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

I installed Application Verifier and during this found out how to use WinDbg from Visual Studio -- really cool to have a debugger one can talk to :-) .  Unfortunately it only told me that I try to release memory at a place where no memory is allocated at the moment and that the address where this happens changes from run to run.  But I couldn't find out why this happens.

I then started to carefully review my code and by the way did a refartoring of the project.  When I was done the error did not appear anymore.  I didn't change the algorithms only reorganized them a little bit.  I let a coworker view over the parts I changed and he couldn't see a mistake either, neither in the refactored version nor in the original version.

Then I rolled my source code back to the version before the refactoring and the error was gone there, too.  I'm really confused about this!  I've only my source checked in and no binaries and object files.  Right now, my two best guesses are:
- either the error is still there just randomly now without symtoms
- or there went something wrong during building, maybe involving some issues with external libraries, what for some reason does not happen anymore.

I will now go on working on my project and hope either the error appears again and I can finde the cause or it will keep silent for ever and ever.

Comment: You should post some real (i.e. compilable), minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: My guess is that you're accessing elements of myVec outside its bounds, and this is crashing the std::vector assignment operator. But you need to refine this post a little more if you want any real help.

Comment: And why not put #include <vector> in your precompiled header? That's what it's for.

Comment: Is it really the case in the actual crashing code that you construct a `MyClass`, call `init()` immediately afterwards (with no other steps in between), and it crashes? If so, what does the `MyClass` constructor do?

Comment: This code should not crash. The cause should be outside this minimal code. Have you logged creation/destruction/copy/assignment with display of vecor size() and capacity() ?

Comment: Possibilities: You kept a pointer or iterator to the old `vector` around past the point of `init` or equivalent.  You access the data beyond the end of the `vector`.  You engaged in some other kind of undefined behavior.

Comment: @Christophe The code cannot possibly crash because it wouldn't compile. That was the point of my first comment :-)

Comment: This is correct code (except missed semicolon after class definition). Here what I see:

At (1) object is in the stack, no elements means - no heap allocation, can't be error here.
At (3) object removed from stack, new object created, some heap allocation happened (1 element)
After main has finished the destructor for **x** is supposed to be called. Only then we have some heap activity. 

So I guess you have to provide your **real** code in order to get solution

Comment: What's sizeof(MyClass)? You're creating object 'x' on the stack, and if the size of MyClass is big enough you risk a stack overflow, which then can lead to all kinds of problems, even heap crashes...

Comment: You might have something causing heap corruption elsewhere. If you're on Linux, try using *Valgrind*. If you're on windows, try using *Application Verifier*.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Unfortunately I was not able to reproduce the error in a minimal example.  I would have to provide the real code (which is large) as StahlRat suggests, but I don't think my boss likes this idea :-(

Comment: @imix: Try anyway, and you're pretty much guaranteed to find the error before you finish.

Comment: @dlf: Actually MyClass lives in another class and gets created there.  I call init from the parents class init.  There I call init right after creation and init of MyClass gets called there quite early in, too, but not immediately.  However the assignment as in (3) is the first use of myVec.  It will not be read or written before!  Moreover in Debug mode I have checked iterator bounds which do not complain either so I would exclude miss access as a cause.

Comment: @Christophe: I did not but I will try.

Comment: @Yakk: I don't think I have pointers to myVec at this early stage but I will double check.  I fear there is some undefined behavior somewhere else.  At (3) VC11 goes into the Move Assignment operator of my vector, checks if the right side is different of the original value (which it is) an calls then _Tidy() on myVec to get rid of the old content.  In _Tidy() the call to free() fails causing the error.  At this point myVec never allocated space befor so there should be nothing to free.  The only thing I can image to go wrong is if myVec is not properly constructed.

Comment: @Stefan: MyClass should not be to big.  It contains some numbers, some pointers and some vectors, all together about 20 data members.

Comment: @jliv902: I didn't know about Application Verifier but I will give it a try.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I tried long! The problem is that I can remove several orthogonal parts of the program each make the error vanish.  That does not bring me any further and it don't leaves me with a working (i.e. broken) minimal example :-(

Comment: @StahlRat: This is what I see, too.  But as I explained in the comment to Yakk, removing the empty vector from the stack fails.  I suppose for some reason there is rubbish in the vector-header (pointer to random address and maybe random size).  The only reason I can imagine for this is undefined behavior but why then not optimizing the assignment (3) of myVec away, too?  Since compiler should know by then this to be undefined either, or not?  Btw. (@)all: Thanks for all the comments!